# iOS Swift didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working

Tags: ios, swift, didselectrowatindexpath

I want to execute a single line of code when the user selects a cell in my TableView.  At runtime, my TableView populates with data okay, and the cells are indeed clickable/selectable. But, when a cell is selected, the '**didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is skipped/not called**.  I'm new to Swift, so maybe I'm overlooking something very simple.  The structure of my code is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class TopicsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

//Number of Sections:
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 2 }

//Number of Rows in Each Section:
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->Int { return 3 }

//Contents of Each Cell:
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Data"
}

//Code below is skipped/ignored at runtime, no matter what I try:  
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { 
print("Hello!") 
}
```

Note: I am not using a gesture recognizer (other threads on this subject suggest a gesture controller could be the culprit)

Comment: Are you returning cell inside cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Is the table view added programmatically or in storyboard? Programmatically / Storyboard: `tableView.delegate = self` or in storyboard check if the delegate has been set.

Comment: Did you connect the table `dataSource` *AND* `delegate` outlets to your view controller? It seems like the methods that are working are the `dataSource` ones and the one that isn't is the `delegate`

Comment: Thanks guys!  EmilioPelaez was right - I included the delegate protocol in the view controller class, but I did not realize I needed to ALSO connect the delegate outlet to the view controller.  Everything appears to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you assign the "delegate" of the tableview?